# Freeze or refrigerate meat for a few days?

Tags: freezing, refrigerator

I usually do the shopping for the week on Sundays, and I often leave the meat in the refrigerator for 5 or 6 days, so I am wondering if it would be better to freeze it immediately after buying it and defrost it later or just keep it in the refrigerator.

Comment: I keep whole meat (pork & cow) in the refrigerator for weeks, on a rack over a pan to collect liquids. It's called "dry aging".

Answer (score 6):

This depends on the type of meat.  Poultry, ground meat, and offal should only be kept at refrigeration temps a couple of days, so you probably want to use first or freeze.  Steaks, chops, and roasts can hang around in the refrigerator a few days more.  By day 6, you are getting near the end of the window, so it might be better to freeze.  Personally, for all cuts, if I am not using in the next two days, I freeze.  Simply because life gets in the way...or plans change, and I may not use the product when I think I am going to.  So, you can't go wrong by freezing, as long as you build defrosting into your weekly plan.  In this case, I move from freezer to fridge one or two days in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't know that poultry lasted only a couple of days, I have left it more than that several times and luckily nothing happened, at least that's what I think. I guess I will follow your advice and freeze it if I'm not consuming it in the next 2 or 3 days, and just defrost it in the refrigerator the day before.

Comment: This is the great thing about fridge-freezers with a 'half way' drawer. Keeps things at about 0 - 0.5° so you don't get the issues with water-ejection on cooking that can happen when you freeze it, yet gives you a few extra days for contingency.